# Invalid Character showing after textarea in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

Please visit this URL using Internet Explorer:
http://devtempleturm.wpengine.com/find-us/

You will see a textarea on the page. At the bottom right corner there is a character coming up (looks like a missing glyph from font), I want to hide that character. Also, If you click inside the textarea same character will be visible inside the textarea.

P.S. It appears fine in Chrome and Safari.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Include your code into the question. If the link you gave here becomes dead, then your question will lose its meaning.

Comment: @LajosArpad Your comment doesn't make sense. Please.

Comment: That's a crazy IE bug!!! `:(`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Not sure why you feel Lajos Arpad's comment doesn't make sense? SO rules state that the code needs to be in the question itself. A link is not good enough because if it goes dead (or the problem gets fixed) this question will be of no use to other users experiencing the same problem.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes, I agree, but at the same time, this issue is something that occurs at a specific instance, and cannot be replicated elsewhere. What would you say about those? And I am a CSS geek, and I tried fiddling with the IE F12 tools, and I am unable to find which code is responsible for this error. How could the OP post a code?

Comment: The OP could post the relevant part of his code, even if @PraveenKumar did not manage to reproduce it. Maybe others will. Or others might observe similarities between their code and Saqib's code. This is a matter of principle. If someone has a problem with a given implementation, then as much info as possible should be given about it. Including, but not limited to picture attachment (not an option here because of the user's rating), relevant part of the source-code, steps to reproduce, if known. The answer is better with source-code than without source-code, obviously.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot please? I am using IE and can't see any characters even if I click on the textarea. Do you mean the "go to page top" button?

Comment: @CagatayUlubay It has been fixed now. Issue was with the font family being used on the website.

Comment: @LajosArpad How does the OP or me, find the *relevant part* of the code, when it is unclear, how it is getting generated. Anyway the problem is fixed. Does my statement makes sense?

Comment: @PraveenKumar, there is no reason to be frustrated. We all try to help each-other here. Our argument from yesterday yielded fine results, as the problem has been solved. Our argument from now helped the OP learn how to proceed on SO. He supposed he had the problem with the font family. So he had a pretty good shot to what the probable problem was. Our debates helps the community, so don't take it personally.

Comment: Okey, then the question should be marked as answered. | FYI everyone: **Problem already solved!!**

Comment: @CagatayUlubay, exactly. He will be able to do so after two days, since he answered his own question. I kindly asked him to do so.

Comment: @LajosArpad Lemme clarify, I am not frustrated. I am just suggesting. Sorry if it meant to you like being rude. I am not rude at all!

Comment: I am not taking it personally. My upvotes/downvotes accepts to your posts are not affected by our debates. I had the impression you took things personally since my sarcastic comment from yesterday. I stand corrected, as you suggested you understood my point. In our case, the relevant part of the code was the font-family and the op suggested before he solved the problem that he suspects that. So he had all the means to share code, but this debate starts to become irrelevant. Let us be happy that the solution was found :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't post the code because it appeared to be a very specific issue.
I suspected that issue was with font that i am using (GothamRounded), and here is more evidence in support for font-issue if I change the font-family for textrea to Arial, then I don't see those symbols inside of the textarea.

Looks like the family doesn't provide the proper glyph for Enter key in IE '\r\n', I have changed the family to a generic one and now it works fine.

The symbol I was getting after the textarea shared the same font issue, I had to use this generic selector for that fix:

```
br {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: Please, do not post an answer to answer a comment. Use the comment section to do so. While I understand your point, an answer should solve, or at least attempt to solve a problem. I believe you should flag your answer and edit your question by adding more details and answer my comments in the comment section ;)

Comment: @LajosArpad Problem is solved for me now. Thanks for your tips on using different sections here on stackoverflow.

Comment: You are welcome. You will be able to accept your answer after two days. I kindly ask you to do so, as other people in the future having similar problem will see there is a solution to the problem.